# revoke invalidate metadata from hue users

Tags: cloudera, impala, hue

How can I revoke INVALIDATE METADATA from all users in HUE as an admin?

I'm eager to find out a solution to keep users' permissions denied on using REFRESH on the corner.

Please help me with that on the refresh request.
REFRESH is a synchronous call, i.e. the client making the call will block waiting for metadata to be reloaded for a table. Also, REFRESH requires the table to be known to Impala but at the same time, it reuses cached metadata to improve the response time of metadata reloading.